# Is there a way to make display grid flexible?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a group of items that I want to behave like `display: flex` but in a `display: grid` layout. What I mean by this is that they are in a grid but the sizes of each grid box are flexible to allow more space for larger titles.

I tried to get the `display: grid` elements to be more flexible with the css selector `grid-auto-columns`

```
<div id="grid">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
</div>

#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a";
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: 200px;
}
```

But I would prefer teat the sections remain rigid in size once they are set instead of being truly flexible

Comment: Is there a reason you cant just use flex and something like `justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I need this in grid because there will be elements that have to line up underneath the top row of grid items and I figured grid would be the best way to do this!

Comment: Can you update your code example, to show a representative example of the contents? Ideally with a picture, so that we can see what you want it to look like.